# How to edit firebase existing document with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I try to build a note taking app in flutter, when i try to edit old note i dont see any change,it takes old value.

[Thats my collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNOPE.png)

My home Page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:story_note/pages/ajoutNote.dart';
import 'package:story_note/pages/authController.dart';
import 'package:story_note/pages/detailNote.dart';
import 'package:story_note/pages/modifierNote.dart';
import 'package:story_note/pages/modifyNote.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomeState createState()=>_HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home>{
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  String nomUser,emailUser;
  Widget _boiteDuDialog(BuildContext, String nom, String email){
    return SimpleDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children:<Widget> [
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children:<Widget> [
              Text('$nom',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,),
              Text('$email',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              Wrap(
                children:<Widget> [
                  FlatButton(color: Colors.red,onPressed:()async{
                    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                    await _auth.signOut();
                    setState(() {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  }, child:Text('Déconnexion')),
                  FlatButton(onPressed:(){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }, child: Text('Annuler'))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    final utilisateur = Provider.of<Utilisateur>(context);
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user){
      setState(() {
        this.currentUser=user;
      });
    });
    String _idUser(){
      if(currentUser!=null){
        return currentUser.uid;
      }else{
        return 'pas id';
      }
    }

    GetCurrentUserData(idUser: utilisateur.idUser).dataUser.forEach((snapshot){
      this.nomUser = snapshot.nomComplet;
      this.emailUser = snapshot.email;

    });
    Widget _buildListItem(DocumentSnapshot document){
      Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs').document(utilisateur.idUser).collection('notes').snapshots();
      Timestamp t = document['timestamp'];
      final DateTime d = t.toDate();
      final DateTime h = DateTime.now();
      final diff = d.difference(h).inMinutes;
      final date = new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(minutes: diff));
      String realdate = timeago.format(date);
      return Dismissible (
          key: new Key(ObjectKey(document.data.keys).toString()),
          onDismissed: (direction)async{
            await Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs').document(utilisateur.idUser).collection('notes').document().delete();
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text('${document['titre']} was deleted',style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
                )
            );
          },
          background: new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child:Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              height: 80,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:Card(
                elevation: 10.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shadowColor: Colors.white24,
                child:new ListTile(
                  onTap:(){
                    print('cest fait');
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ModifierNote(
                      titre:document['titre'],
                      note:document['note']
                    )));
                  },
                  leading: Icon(Icons.mood_rounded,color: Colors.blue,size: 30,),
                  title: new Text('${document['titre']}',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.justify,),
                  subtitle: new Text('${document['note']}',maxLines: 1,),
                  trailing: new Text(realdate),
                ),
              )

          )
      );

    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Story Notes',),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded), onPressed:(){

          }),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed:()=>showDialog(context: context,builder: (context)=>
              _boiteDuDialog(context,nomUser,emailUser))),
        ],
      ),

      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
        child:StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs').document(utilisateur.idUser).collection('notes').snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData)
              return Text('loading....');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder:(context,index)=>
                  _buildListItem(snapshot.data.documents[index]),


            );
          },

        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Icon(Icons.note_add,),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AjoutNote()));

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my Modification page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ModifierNote extends StatefulWidget{
  final String titre,note;
  ModifierNote({this.titre,this.note});
  @override
  ModifierNoteState createState()=> ModifierNoteState();
}
class ModifierNoteState extends State<ModifierNote>{
  final CollectionReference collectionUser = Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs');
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _titreValid = true;
  bool _noteValid = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() {
        this.currentUser = user;
      });
    });
    String _idUser(){
      if(currentUser!=null){
        return currentUser.uid;
      }else{
        return 'Pas id';
      }
    }
    String titre1 = widget.titre;
    String note1 = widget.note;
    final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();
    modifierNotes()async{
      await collectionUser.document(_idUser()).collection('notes')
          .document('note')
          .setData({
        'titre': titre1,
        'note': note1,
        'timestamp':timestamp
      });
      this.setState(() {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text('Notes'),
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(
              onPressed:()async{
                if(_formkey.currentState.validate()){
                  modifierNotes();
                }

              },
              child:Text('Modifier')
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child:Card(
              elevation: 15,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children:<Widget> [
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: titre1,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Titre',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.speaker_notes_sharp),
                      ),
                      validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Entrez un titre' : null,
                      onChanged: (val)=>setState(()=>titre1 = val),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: note1,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: 5000,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Comment vous sentez vous ?',
                        hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Entrez une note' : null,
                      onChanged: (val)=>setState(()=>note1 = val),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );


  }
}
```

And Addpage:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AjoutNote extends StatefulWidget{
  AjoutNoteState createState()=> AjoutNoteState();
}

class AjoutNoteState extends State<AjoutNote>{
String titre;
String note;
final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final CollectionReference collectionUser = Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs');
final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();
FirebaseUser currentUser;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() {
        this.currentUser = user;
      });
    });
    String _idUser(){
      if(currentUser!=null){
        return currentUser.uid;
      }else{
        return 'Pas id';
      }
    }
    enegistrezNote()async{
        await collectionUser.document(_idUser()).collection('notes')
            .document('note')
            .setData({
          'titre': titre,
          'note': note,
          'timestamp':timestamp
        });
        this.setState(() {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ajouter une note'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(onPressed:(){
            if(_formkey.currentState.validate()){
              enegistrezNote();
            }
          },
            child: Text("Enregistrez"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
          child:SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 15,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children:<Widget> [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Titre',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.speaker_notes_sharp)
                      ),
                      onChanged: (val)=>titre=val,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: 5000,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Comment vous sentez vous ?',
                        hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (val)=>note=val,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }
}
```

When i try to modify i dont see any changes.

Answer (score 1):

use update Method in place of set, I have made changes for you:

```
modifierNotes()async{
  await collectionUser.document(_idUser()).collection('notes')
      .document('note')
      .update({
    'titre': titre1,
    'note': note1,
    'timestamp':timestamp
  });
  this.setState(() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  });
}
```

Comment: E/flutter (22599): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Comment: my bad it should be .upade instead of updateData, I have updated my answer

Comment: The method update isnt defined for the type DocumentReference

Comment: But the same code seems to be working for me just fine without any errors.